# BRING someone or BRING TO someone

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, personal-pronouns, prepositional-verbs, intransitive-preposition

Which one is more correct:

> They are thankful for the happiness and the joy they bring them every day

OR

> They are thankful for the happiness and the joy they bring **to** them every day?

Here, "they" means family and friends.

Comment: If you say "bring to" that might suggest they carry happiness and joy in a box. IMO the first is better, and even if they bring food and drink, I would still omit 'to'. OTOH a leader might say "bring it/them to me."

Comment: @WeatherVane Except in the north of England where "bring it me" and "give it me", or "show it her" or "tell it them" are idiomatic.

Comment: @WS2 nice, do they say "sock it me"?

Comment: @WeatherVane Quite possibly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bring to" implies that a tangible object(s) is being brought to the people in question. I would omit the "to" in this context.
There are a few other grammatical mistakes. This sentence is very awkward. As a general rule, one should avoid using too many of the same pronouns in a single sentence. Instead, one should specify the noun in question. Also, "The happiness and the joy" should be conjoined into "the happiness and joy". A much smoother sentence would be "They are thankful for the happiness and joy that X brings them every day".

Comment: Bring to doesn't imply a tangible object.  It is often heard in relation to emotion or feeling.  But I agree, 'to' is a pointless filler word.